# Android Make transparent half of view

Tags: android, xml, image, transparent

I can make an image button like "1" with android xml and bitmap repeat.

But I want to make it like "2" (half transparent) with android xml. How can I make it?

> [image]

Comment: u can use image in button background...

Comment: Do you know gradient & Shape in Android ?

Comment: Yes i know  gradient & Shape.but what i do? if i want it have Stripes.[link](http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-01/95376529393480982679.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Create half_transparent_bg.xml as follows:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<gradient
    android:angle="180"
    android:endColor="#00ffffff"
    android:startColor="#ffffffff"/>
</shape>
```

You can change the background of the image button to this drawable

or if you want to stack it to the bitmap repeat put the bitmap with the shape drawable above in layer-list

EDIT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item>
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/close"
        android:tileMode="repeat" />
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:angle="180"
            android:endColor="#00ffffff"
            android:startColor="#ffffffff" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Where you can put your red stripe instead of close

Comment: it is ok. but what i do? if i want it have Stripes.[link](http://upload7.ir/imgs/2014-01/95376529393480982679.jpg)

Comment: Thanks youssef. but i think my problem is complex

Answer (score 0):

This is my project view.
I want remove solid white color  and keep white strips.
transparent half  of strips.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5vJi.png

and i is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF"
            android:startColor="#00FFFFFF" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:antialias="true"
        android:dither="true"
        android:filter="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ww"
        android:tileMode="repeat" >
        <shape>
        </shape>
    </bitmap>
</item>
```

Comment: It is my first step in android. help me  to do it.