# How to make half of an imageView transparent?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

I have an `ImageView` and i want to make half of its bitmap transparent without changing size.
anyone can help?

I want to change this image:

[image]

to this one:

[image]

but i don't want change the height and width.

Comment: post image design exactly what you want.

Comment: exactly , i want cut half of an image without changing the resolution

Comment: @BhupatBheda please check edited question

Comment: okay,  you want to display 50% transparent image or remove that portion?

Comment: @BhupatBheda i want to remove that portion . the image width is important

Comment: plz, check my post I posted a code for you.

Comment: did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

**try this:**

```
ImageView image= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
image.setAlpha(127); //value: [0-255]. Where 0 is fully transparent and 255 is fully opaque.
```

**note:**

You can use Float values in **setAlpha()**

**Like this :**

```
image.setAlpha(0.5f);
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/gd73i" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="-250dp"/>
```

please check you want like this or try with the below code in xml.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/col_white">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/gd73i" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#fff">

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1">

               </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

with the white space also you can do like above code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);   
BitmapDrawable bd = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.load);    
Bitmap bm = bd.getBitmap();    
Paint paint = new Paint();    
paint.setAlpha(60); 
//provide transparent value here    
canvas.drawBitmap(bm, 0, 0, paint);
```

Comment: it will affect all the image

Comment: you want half of your image will be transparent and rest will keep as usual.

Comment: yeah its exactly what i want

Comment: You can see this questions, it can help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381135/android-make-transparent-half-of-view